# How to change color of the bar in ModernCV latex

Tags: colors, latex, line, document

I need to change the color of the bar related to the sections in the modernCV class in Latex.
For example I defined a color "carmine" and I won't both the name of the section and the line related to it with that color. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\usepackage[scale = 0.9, right = 2cm, left = 2cm, top = 1cm, bottom = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\recomputelengths
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

% Define color
\definecolor{carmine}{rgb}{0.59, 0.0, 0.09}

\moderncvcolor{blue} % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

% if you want to change the width of the column with the dates:
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4.1cm} 

% personal data
\name{} 
\address{}
\phone[mobile]{}                   
\email{}   

% Picture:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{\color{carmine}{Blablabla}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load the same package multiple times with different options

Comment: You can't use `\label` without caption

Comment: Your code does not compile

Comment: You must not use `\begin{figure}...` before your document starts

Comment: The syntax `\color{carmine}{...}` is wrong

Answer (score 5):

`moderncv` uses a colour called `color1` (not really the most descriptive variable name...) for all these highlighting, you can simply modify this color:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual} 

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}

\definecolor{carmine}{rgb}{0.59, 0.0, 0.09}
\colorlet{color1}{carmine}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{BlaBla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Just want I needed. I also posted an answer based on your post here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109496). Hope that is ok ( I cited your post as a reference).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Nice to see you here! :)